# ManyToMany Symfony2: Вывод данных с разных таблиц

Tags: doctrine2, twig, php, symfony2

Здравствуйте.

В общем, использую symfony2 и doctrine2.

Вопрос следующего характера.
Есть 2 сущности Price и Suppliers. Между ними есть связь ManyToMany.

Логика такова:
Есть позиция в табле Price, эта позиция связана с Табло Suppliers, в частности с полем id. Так вот нужно выводить всю информацию на сайте с таблицы Price, и значение поля supname с таблицы Suppliers. Вот исходники.

**P.S.** Буду очень благодарен за помощь, так как документация мне не помогла в моей вопросе.

---

***Price.php***

```
<?php
namespace Vega\VegaBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Vega\VegaBundle\Entity\PriceRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="Price")
 */
class Price
{
/**
* @ORM\Id
* @ORM\Column(type="integer")
* @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
*/
protected $id;

/**
* @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
*
*/
protected $name;

/**
* @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
*/
protected $brand;
/**
* @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
*/
protected $decription;
/**
* @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 */
protected $cost;

/**
* @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Suppliers", mappedBy="Price")
*/
protected $sup;

public function __construct()
{
$this->sup = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

**Suppliers.php**

```
<?php
namespace Vega\VegaBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Vega\VegaBundle\Entity\SuppliersRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="Suppliers")
 */
class Suppliers
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     *
     */
    protected $supname;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Price", inversedBy="Suppliers") 
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="Price_sup")
     */
    protected $supid;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->supid = new ArrayCollection();
    }
```

**Controller.php**

```
<?php
namespace Vega\VegaBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Vega\VegaBundle\Entity\Price;
use Vega\VegaBundle\Entity\Suppliers;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{

    public function indexAction()
        {

            $em=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('VegaBundle:Price');
            $products=$em->findBy(array(),array('id'=>'ASC'));

            if (!$products) {
                throw $this->createNotFoundException('Не найдено деталей');
            }
            else{
                return $this->render('VegaBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array('price' => $products));
            }
        }
}
```

**Шаблон Twig**

```
    {% block body %}
        <div style="text-align:center;">
            Вывод деталей
                <table style="width: 800px;margin: 0 auto;">
                    <thead>
                        <th>Ид</th>
                        <th>Название</th>
                        <th>Цена</th>
                        <th>Бренд</th>
                        <th>Описание</th>
                        <th>Поставщик</th>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    {% for price in price %}
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ price.id }}</td>
                            <td>{{ price.name }}</td>
                            <td>{{ price.cost }}</td>
                            <td>{{ price.brand }}</td>
                            <td>{{ price.decription }}</td>
                            <td></td>
                        </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
        </div>
 {% endblock %}
```

Comment: > Так вот нужно выводить всю информацию на сайте с таблицы Price, и значение поля supname с таблицы Suppliers. 

ManyToMany подразумевает, что для одного price может быть от нуля до бесконечности suppliers. Каким образом должно появиться одно конкретное значение?

Comment: Попробуйте добавить ссылки на использование связанных таблиц, в Price - Suppliers и наоборот, без этого точно работать не будет

Comment: @Etki, я вот тоже думаю, что тут скорее всего будет OneToMany в Suppliers и ManyToOne в Price

Comment: Все же вопрос остался открытым, мне нужна 2-х сторонняя связь, что бы я так же как и через Price получал инфу с таблицы Suppliers, так же и по ключу с таблы Suppliers получал инфу с таблицы Price. То есть связь ManyToMany. Я делал дамп Массива который получил через контроллер. Информация с таблы Price выводится, а вот что касательно таблы Suppliers ничего не возвращает. Можете пожалуйста подсказать как сделать запрос таким образом что бы возвращалось все. Заранее благодарен!=)

Comment: @meylah15

> Все же вопрос остался открытым

вот именно

> Каким образом должно появиться одно конкретное значение?

пока не прояснен этот механизм, ничего ответить нельзя.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
                {% for price in price %}
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ price.id }}</td>
                        <td>{{ price.name }}</td>
                        <td>{{ price.cost }}</td>
                        <td>{{ price.brand }}</td>
                        <td>{{ price.decription }}</td>
                        <td>{% for sup in price.sup %}<span>{{ sup.supname }}</span>{% endfor %}</td>
                    </tr>
                {% endfor %}
```